# Java to Dart - Hash Table Open Addressing Implementation

Tags: java, dart, hashtable

```
/**
 * Base class for hashtables with an open addressing collision resolution method such as linear
 * probing, quadratic probing and double hashing.
 *
 * @author William Fiset, william.alexandre.fiset@gmail.com
 */
package com.williamfiset.algorithms.datastructures.hashtable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public abstract class HashTableOpenAddressingBase<K, V> implements Iterable<K> {

  protected double loadFactor;
  protected int capacity, threshold, modificationCount;

  // 'usedBuckets' counts the total number of used buckets inside the
  // hash-table (includes cells marked as deleted). While 'keyCount'
  // tracks the number of unique keys currently inside the hash-table.
  protected int usedBuckets, keyCount;

  // These arrays store the key-value pairs.
  protected K[] keys;
  protected V[] values;

  // Special marker token used to indicate the deletion of a key-value pair
  protected final K TOMBSTONE = (K) (new Object());

  private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 7;
  private static final double DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.65;

  protected HashTableOpenAddressingBase() {
    this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR);
  }

  protected HashTableOpenAddressingBase(int capacity) {
    this(capacity, DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR);
  }

  // Designated constructor
  protected HashTableOpenAddressingBase(int capacity, double loadFactor) {
    if (capacity <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal capacity: " + capacity);

    if (loadFactor <= 0 || Double.isNaN(loadFactor) || Double.isInfinite(loadFactor))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal loadFactor: " + loadFactor);

    this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
    this.capacity = Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, capacity);
    adjustCapacity();
    threshold = (int) (this.capacity * loadFactor);

    keys = (K[]) new Object[this.capacity];
    values = (V[]) new Object[this.capacity];
  }

  // These three methods are used to dictate how the probing is to actually
  // occur for whatever open addressing scheme you are implementing.
  protected abstract void setupProbing(K key);

  protected abstract int probe(int x);

  // Adjusts the capacity of the hash table after it's been made larger.
  // This is important to be able to override because the size of the hashtable
  // controls the functionality of the probing function.
  protected abstract void adjustCapacity();

  // Increases the capacity of the hash table.
  protected void increaseCapacity() {
    capacity = (2 * capacity) + 1;
  }

  public void clear() {
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
      keys[i] = null;
      values[i] = null;
    }
    keyCount = usedBuckets = 0;
    modificationCount++;
  }

  // Returns the number of keys currently inside the hash-table
  public int size() {
    return keyCount;
  }

  // Returns the capacity of the hashtable (used mostly for testing)
  public int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
  }

  // Returns true/false depending on whether the hash-table is empty
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return keyCount == 0;
  }

  public V put(K key, V value) {
    return insert(key, value);
  }

  public V add(K key, V value) {
    return insert(key, value);
  }

  // Returns true/false on whether a given key exists within the hash-table.
  public boolean containsKey(K key) {
    return hasKey(key);
  }

  // Returns a list of keys found in the hash table
  public List<K> keys() {
    List<K> hashtableKeys = new ArrayList<>(size());
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
      if (keys[i] != null && keys[i] != TOMBSTONE) hashtableKeys.add(keys[i]);
    return hashtableKeys;
  }

  // Returns a list of non-unique values found in the hash table
  public List<V> values() {
    List<V> hashtableValues = new ArrayList<>(size());
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
      if (keys[i] != null && keys[i] != TOMBSTONE) hashtableValues.add(values[i]);
    return hashtableValues;
  }

  // Double the size of the hash-table
  protected void resizeTable() {
    increaseCapacity();
    adjustCapacity();

    threshold = (int) (capacity * loadFactor);

    K[] oldKeyTable = (K[]) new Object[capacity];
    V[] oldValueTable = (V[]) new Object[capacity];

    // Perform key table pointer swap
    K[] keyTableTmp = keys;
    keys = oldKeyTable;
    oldKeyTable = keyTableTmp;

    // Perform value table pointer swap
    V[] valueTableTmp = values;
    values = oldValueTable;
    oldValueTable = valueTableTmp;

    // Reset the key count and buckets used since we are about to
    // re-insert all the keys into the hash-table.
    keyCount = usedBuckets = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < oldKeyTable.length; i++) {
      if (oldKeyTable[i] != null && oldKeyTable[i] != TOMBSTONE)
        insert(oldKeyTable[i], oldValueTable[i]);
      oldValueTable[i] = null;
      oldKeyTable[i] = null;
    }
  }

  // Converts a hash value to an index. Essentially, this strips the
  // negative sign and places the hash value in the domain [0, capacity)
  protected final int normalizeIndex(int keyHash) {
    return (keyHash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % capacity;
  }

  // Finds the greatest common denominator of a and b.
  protected static final int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
  }

  // Place a key-value pair into the hash-table. If the value already
  // exists inside the hash-table then the value is updated.
  public V insert(K key, V val) {
    if (key == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null key");
    if (usedBuckets >= threshold) resizeTable();

    setupProbing(key);
    final int offset = normalizeIndex(key.hashCode());

    for (int i = offset, j = -1, x = 1; ; i = normalizeIndex(offset + probe(x++))) {

      // The current slot was previously deleted
      if (keys[i] == TOMBSTONE) {
        if (j == -1) j = i;

        // The current cell already contains a key
      } else if (keys[i] != null) {
        // The key we're trying to insert already exists in the hash-table,
        // so update its value with the most recent value
        if (keys[i].equals(key)) {

          V oldValue = values[i];
          if (j == -1) {
            values[i] = val;
          } else {
            keys[i] = TOMBSTONE;
            values[i] = null;
            keys[j] = key;
            values[j] = val;
          }
          modificationCount++;
          return oldValue;
        }

        // Current cell is null so an insertion/update can occur
      } else {
        // No previously encountered deleted buckets
        if (j == -1) {
          usedBuckets++;
          keyCount++;
          keys[i] = key;
          values[i] = val;

          // Previously seen deleted bucket. Instead of inserting
          // the new element at i where the null element is insert
          // it where the deleted token was found.
        } else {
          keyCount++;
          keys[j] = key;
          values[j] = val;
        }

        modificationCount++;
        return null;
      }
    }
  }

  // Returns true/false on whether a given key exists within the hash-table
  public boolean hasKey(K key) {
    if (key == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null key");

    setupProbing(key);
    final int offset = normalizeIndex(key.hashCode());

    // Start at the original hash value and probe until we find a spot where our key
    // is or hit a null element in which case our element does not exist.
    for (int i = offset, j = -1, x = 1; ; i = normalizeIndex(offset + probe(x++))) {

      // Ignore deleted cells, but record where the first index
      // of a deleted cell is found to perform lazy relocation later.
      if (keys[i] == TOMBSTONE) {

        if (j == -1) j = i;

        // We hit a non-null key, perhaps it's the one we're looking for.
      } else if (keys[i] != null) {

        // The key we want is in the hash-table!
        if (keys[i].equals(key)) {

          // If j != -1 this means we previously encountered a deleted cell.
          // We can perform an optimization by swapping the entries in cells
          // i and j so that the next time we search for this key it will be
          // found faster. This is called lazy deletion/relocation.
          if (j != -1) {
            // Swap the key-value pairs of positions i and j.
            keys[j] = keys[i];
            values[j] = values[i];
            keys[i] = TOMBSTONE;
            values[i] = null;
          }
          return true;
        }

        // Key was not found in the hash-table :/
      } else return false;
    }
  }

  // Get the value associated with the input key.
  // NOTE: returns null if the value is null AND also returns
  // null if the key does not exists.
  public V get(K key) {
    if (key == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null key");

    setupProbing(key);
    final int offset = normalizeIndex(key.hashCode());

    // Start at the original hash value and probe until we find a spot where our key
    // is or we hit a null element in which case our element does not exist.
    for (int i = offset, j = -1, x = 1; ; i = normalizeIndex(offset + probe(x++))) {

      // Ignore deleted cells, but record where the first index
      // of a deleted cell is found to perform lazy relocation later.
      if (keys[i] == TOMBSTONE) {

        if (j == -1) j = i;

        // We hit a non-null key, perhaps it's the one we're looking for.
      } else if (keys[i] != null) {

        // The key we want is in the hash-table!
        if (keys[i].equals(key)) {

          // If j != -1 this means we previously encountered a deleted cell.
          // We can perform an optimization by swapping the entries in cells
          // i and j so that the next time we search for this key it will be
          // found faster. This is called lazy deletion/relocation.
          if (j != -1) {
            // Swap key-values pairs at indexes i and j.
            keys[j] = keys[i];
            values[j] = values[i];
            keys[i] = TOMBSTONE;
            values[i] = null;
            return values[j];
          } else {
            return values[i];
          }
        }

        // Element was not found in the hash-table :/
      } else return null;
    }
  }

  // Removes a key from the map and returns the value.
  // NOTE: returns null if the value is null AND also returns
  // null if the key does not exists.
  public V remove(K key) {
    if (key == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null key");

    setupProbing(key);
    final int offset = normalizeIndex(key.hashCode());

    // Starting at the original hash probe until we find a spot where our key is
    // or we hit a null element in which case our element does not exist.
    for (int i = offset, x = 1; ; i = normalizeIndex(offset + probe(x++))) {

      // Ignore deleted cells
      if (keys[i] == TOMBSTONE) continue;

      // Key was not found in hash-table.
      if (keys[i] == null) return null;

      // The key we want to remove is in the hash-table!
      if (keys[i].equals(key)) {
        keyCount--;
        modificationCount++;
        V oldValue = values[i];
        keys[i] = TOMBSTONE;
        values[i] = null;
        return oldValue;
      }
    }
  }

  // Return a String view of this hash-table.
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
      if (keys[i] != null && keys[i] != TOMBSTONE) sb.append(keys[i] + " => " + values[i] + ", ");
    sb.append("}");

    return sb.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<K> iterator() {
    // Before the iteration begins record the number of modifications
    // done to the hash-table. This value should not change as we iterate
    // otherwise a concurrent modification has occurred :0
    final int MODIFICATION_COUNT = modificationCount;

    return new Iterator<K>() {
      int index, keysLeft = keyCount;

      @Override
      public boolean hasNext() {
        // The contents of the table have been altered
        if (MODIFICATION_COUNT != modificationCount) throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        return keysLeft != 0;
      }

      // Find the next element and return it
      @Override
      public K next() {
        while (keys[index] == null || keys[index] == TOMBSTONE) index++;
        keysLeft--;
        return keys[index++];
      }

      @Override
      public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```
/**
 * An implementation of a hash-table using open addressing with quadratic probing as a collision
 * resolution method.
 *
 * <p>In this implementation we are using the following probing function: H(k, x) = h(k) + f(x) mod
 * 2^n
 *
 * <p>Where h(k) is the hash for the given key, f(x) = (x + x^2) / 2 and n is a natural number. We
 * are using this probing function because it is guaranteed to find an empty cell (i.e it generates
 * all the numbers in the range [0, 2^n) without repetition for the first 2^n numbers).
 *
 * @author William Fiset, william.alexandre.fiset@gmail.com
 */
package com.williamfiset.algorithms.datastructures.hashtable;

public class HashTableQuadraticProbing<K, V> extends HashTableOpenAddressingBase<K, V> {

  public HashTableQuadraticProbing() {
    super();
  }

  public HashTableQuadraticProbing(int capacity) {
    super(capacity);
  }

  // Designated constructor
  public HashTableQuadraticProbing(int capacity, double loadFactor) {
    super(capacity, loadFactor);
  }

  // Given a number this method finds the next
  // power of two above this value.
  private static int nextPowerOfTwo(int n) {
    return Integer.highestOneBit(n) << 1;
  }

  // No setup required for quadratic probing.
  @Override
  protected void setupProbing(K key) {}

  @Override
  protected int probe(int x) {
    // Quadratic probing function (x^2+x)/2
    return (x * x + x) >> 1;
  }

  // Increase the capacity of the hashtable to the next power of two.
  @Override
  protected void increaseCapacity() {
    capacity = nextPowerOfTwo(capacity);
  }

  // Adjust the capacity of the hashtable to be a power of two.
  @Override
  protected void adjustCapacity() {
    int pow2 = Integer.highestOneBit(capacity);
    if (capacity == pow2) return;
    increaseCapacity();
  }
}
```

Implement this in Dart.

I tried to translate it but my code doesn't work.

'HashTableOpenAddressingBase.iterator' ('Iterator<K?> Function()') isn't a valid override of 'Iterable.iterator' ('Iterator<K> Function()'). dart(invalid_override) iterable.dart(169, 19): The member being overridden.

Unhandled exception: type 'Object' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast #0 new HashTableOpenAddressingBase._withCapacity (file:///D:/Documents/Development/projects/dsa/bin/hash%20table/hashtable_open_addressing_base.dart:34:26) #1 new HashTableOpenAddressingBase._withDefaults (file:///D:/Documents/Development/projects/dsa/bin/hash%20table/hashtable_open_addressing_base.dart:20:14) #2 new HashTableOpenAddressingBase (file:///D:/Documents/Development/projects/dsa/bin/hash%20table/hashtable_open_addressing_base.dart:14:40) #3 new HashTableQuadraticProbing (file:///D:/Documents/Development/projects/dsa/bin/hash%20table/hashtable_open_addressing_base.dart:271:33) #4 main (file:///D:/Documents/Development/projects/dsa/bin/hash%20table/hashtable_open_addressing_base.dart:305:19) #5 _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:296:19) #6 _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12)

Comment: You have forgot posting your Dart code.